Deriving the formulas for the Coupon Collector Problem
I am learning about the Coupon Collector problem in math (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem). Let's say we have $n$ distinct coupons (or items) to collect. Here are some well known answers::

Expected number of draws:
The expected number of draws $E[T]$ to collect all $n$ coupons is:
$$ E[T] = n\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{i} $$

Probability of collecting all coupons:
The probability $P(T \leq k)$ of collecting all coupons within $k$ draws is:
$$ P(T \leq k) = \frac{n!}{n^k} \sum_{i=0}^n (-1)^i \binom{n}{i} (n-i)^k $$

Expected time to collect the $i$-th new coupon:
Let $X_i$ be the number of draws needed to collect the $i$-th new coupon after having $i-1$ coupons. Then:
$$ E[X_i] = \frac{n}{n-i+1} $$

Variance:
The variance of the total number of draws $T$ is:
$$ \text{Var}(T) = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{n^2}{(n-i+1)^2} - \left(n\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{i}\right)^2 $$


I am trying to derive these answers myself.

1) Expected Numbers of Draws.
Define $X_i$ as the number of draws needed to collect the $i$-th new coupon after having collected $i-1$ coupons. The probability of drawing a new coupon when we already have $i-1$ coupons is (this is just by definition):
$$ P(\text{new coupon}) = \frac{n-(i-1)}{n} = \frac{n-i+1}{n} $$
This means $X_i$ follows a geometric distribution with probability $p = \frac{n-i+1}{n}$. This is because a geometric distribution models the expected time until a certain event happens. The expected value of a geometric distribution is $\frac{1}{p}$. Thus:
$$ E[X_i] = \frac{1}{p} = \frac{n}{n-i+1} $$
The total number of draws $T$ is the sum of all $X_i$:
$$ T = X_1 + X_2 + ... + X_n $$
By the linearity of expectation:
$$ E[T] = E[X_1] + E[X_2] + ... + E[X_n] $$
Substituting:
$$ E[T] = \frac{n}{n} + \frac{n}{n-1} + \frac{n}{n-2} + ... + \frac{n}{2} + \frac{n}{1} $$
This can be rewritten as:
$$ E[T] = n \left(\frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{n-1} + \frac{1}{n-2} + ... + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{1}\right) $$

2) Probability of collecting all coupons
Let $A_i$ be the event that the $i$-th coupon is not collected in $k$ draws.
The probability of $A_i$ occurring is:
$$ P(A_i) = \left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)^k $$
This is because for each draw, the probability of not getting the $i$-th coupon is $\frac{n-1}{n}$, and we do this $k$ times.
To find the probability of at least one $A_i$ occurring (i.e., not all coupons collected). This is where we use the principle of inclusion-exclusion (I posted a previous question about this here Deriving the Inclusion-Exclusion Formula).
$$ P(\text{at least one } A_i) = \sum_{i=1}^n P(A_i) - \sum_{i<j} P(A_i \cap A_j) + \sum_{i<j<k} P(A_i \cap A_j \cap A_k) - ... + (-1)^{n+1} P(A_1 \cap A_2 \cap ... \cap A_n) $$
Calculating:

$P(A_i) = \left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)^k$ for any $i$
$P(A_i \cap A_j) = \left(\frac{n-2}{n}\right)^k$ for any $i$ and $j$
In general, $P(m \text{ coupons not collected}) = \left(\frac{n-m}{n}\right)^k$

Each of these mini sums needs to be augmented with a combinatorics term:
$$ P(\text{at least one } A_i) = \sum_{i=1}^n (-1)^{i+1} \binom{n}{i} \left(\frac{n-i}{n}\right)^k $$
Thus, the probability of collecting all coupons is the complement of this:
$$ P(T \leq k) = 1 - \sum_{i=1}^n (-1)^{i+1} \binom{n}{i} \left(\frac{n-i}{n}\right)^k $$
Simplifying:
$$ P(T \leq k) = \sum_{i=0}^n (-1)^i \binom{n}{i} \left(\frac{n-i}{n}\right)^k $$
$$ P(T \leq k) = \frac{1}{n^k} \sum_{i=0}^n (-1)^i \binom{n}{i} (n-i)^k $$
This does not match exactly, but I think its close?

3) Expected time to collect the $i$-th new coupon
$$ E[X_i] = \frac{n}{n-i+1} $$
Let $X_i$ be the number of draws needed to collect the $i$-th new coupon after having $i-1$ coupons.
When we have $i-1$ coupons, there are $n-(i-1) = n-i+1$ coupons left to collect.
The probability of getting a new coupon on any single draw is:
$$ p = \frac{n-(i-1)}{n} = \frac{n-i+1}{n} $$
Again, this scenario follows a geometric distribution. In a geometric distribution, we're counting the number of trials until the first success, where each trial has probability $p$ of success.
For a geometric distribution, the expected value is given by $\frac{1}{p}$. Therefore:
$$ E[X_i] = \frac{1}{p} = \frac{1}{\frac{n-i+1}{n}} $$
Simplifying:
$$ E[X_i] = \frac{n}{n-i+1} $$

4) Variance
I think for this one we can just use the classic variance/expectation formula:
Earlier I wrote $T = X_1 + X_2 + ... + X_n$, where $X_i$ is the number of draws to get the $i$-th new coupon.
We know that $E[X_i] = \frac{n}{n-i+1}$.
For a geometric distribution (which $X_i$ follows), the variance is given by:
$$ \text{Var}(X_i) = \frac{1-p}{p^2} $$
and $p = \frac{n-i+1}{n}$ is the probability of success.
Substituting this $p$:
$$ \text{Var}(X_i) = \frac{1-\frac{n-i+1}{n}}{(\frac{n-i+1}{n})^2} = \frac{n-(n-i+1)}{(\frac{n-i+1}{n})^2} = \frac{i-1}{(\frac{n-i+1}{n})^2} $$
$$ \text{Var}(X_i) = \frac{n^2(i-1)}{(n-i+1)^2} $$
To find $\text{Var}(T)$, we just need to use the sum of $T = X_1 + X_2 + ... + X_n$
$$ \text{Var}(T) = \sum_{i=1}^n \text{Var}(X_i) = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{n^2(i-1)}{(n-i+1)^2} $$
$$ \text{Var}(T) = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{n^2}{(n-i+1)^2} - \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{n^2}{(n-i+1)^2} $$
Again use the classic variance formula $E[T] = n\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{i}$. We can use the formula $\text{Var}(T) = E[T^2] - (E[T])^2$:
$$ \text{Var}(T) = E[T^2] - \left(n\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{i}\right)^2 $$
Combining everything:
$$ \text{Var}(T) = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{n^2}{(n-i+1)^2} - \left(n\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{i}\right)^2 $$

Did I do OK here?

Is the formula for $\mathbb P(T\le k)$ "well-known" as you mention in the beginning, or is it one of your results here? In any case: the $n!$ in $$P(T \leq k) = \frac{\color{red}{n!}}{n^k} \sum_{i=0}^n (-1)^i \binom{n}{i} (n-i)^k$$ seems wrong.

@KurtG. : thanks ... I think I might have copied these incorrectly from the blackboard in class... I will revise

For #1: You got it!
For #2: The $n!$ is wrong. If you let $k=1$ then this produces a probability of $P(T\leq 1)=n!$ (not good).
For #3: Again, correct. This was part of #1, really.
For #4: Correct as far as I can see. Note that the $X_i$ are independent because each draw is independent, so how long it takes to get the $i$th coupon and how long to the $j$th coupon have no relationship with each other.
